# C++ - Strip types from parameter list in a macro argument

Tags: c++, macros, variadic, variadic-macros

I have a macro which takes a parameter list as an argument, as shown here:

```
#define func(returnType, name, args)                  \
   static inline returnType fn_ ## name ## impl args; \
   DLL_EXPORT returnType fn_ ## name args {           \
      // What to do here?                             \
   }                                                  \
   static inline returnType fn_ ## name ## impl args  \
```

Designed to be used like this:

```
func(void, a, (int a, float b)) {
   std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

My issue is that I need to take the parameter list given, use it to define the header for the function and pass the arguments on to the implementation.

Is there any way to strip the types from parameter list, such that I would be left with "(a, b)" from "(int a, float b)"?

I tried to do it with variadic templates, but I need the function to be exported with extern "C" in order to utilize the C++ library from another application, which is not aware of how the C++ code is compiled. Thus, unaware of how name mangling etc, is handled.
From what I have gathered, I have not found any way to export such variadic templates with extern "C".

Comment: [Loosely related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47086790/3233393), might give you some ideas.

Comment: Even if you could deal with name mangling, it would not work either. Variadic templates are processed at ***compile time***, not at run time. Key, fundamental difference. It's not clear exactly what this is trying to accomplish, but C++ simply does not fundamentally work this way. Interfacing with C libraries involves writing simple, plain functions that take a fixed set of parameters, and wrapping them in `extern "C"`. That's it. End of story. If those wrappers need to invoke variadic templates, that's fine. But if you can't use this model, whatever you're trying to do, it will not work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am, however, looking for a compile time solution, that is why I'm looking into macros. I am not trying to define the parameter list at runtime.

Comment: You could use a pre-pre-processor of your own devising, written in (say) Python or Perl or Ruby.  Might sound crazy (or might be crazy) but I've seen such kind of crazy successfully used in real world projects, and it works well enough.  Not to my liking, but it's a tool to ostensibly make development easier.

Comment: It's more like a request of autogen tool/script to me when it comes to pre-preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to strip the types from parameter list, such that I would be left with "(a, b)" from "(int a, float b)"?

No, it is not possible. Once `int a` is one argument, it's one argument, and nothing you can do in preprocessor can split them.

It's typical to pass types and variable names as separate tokens - `int, a, float, b` and then shuffle them later. For that you might be interested in my other answers - [How to use variadic macro arguments in both a function definition and a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284705/how-to-use-variadic-macro-arguments-in-both-a-function-definition-and-a-function) , [What are options to get multiple variable lists in a variadic macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088599/what-are-options-to-get-multiple-variable-lists-in-a-variadic-macro) , [c++ variadic macro: how to retrieve arguments values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68498360/c-variadic-macro-how-to-retrieve-arguments-values) .